# What does it mean when a Julia error references a line number that doesn't exist?

Tags: julia

I'm getting an odd error in Julia today, one that references a line number that doesn't exist.

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: T not defined
 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488 (repeats 3 times)
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:415
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:239
 in _start() at ./client.jl:318
while loading /home/peter/Code/Spark.jl/src/rdd.jl, in expression starting on line 480
while loading /home/peter/Code/Spark.jl/src/core.jl, in expression starting on line 17
while loading /home/peter/Code/Spark.jl/src/Spark.jl, in expression starting on line 19
```

Now, what's odd here is that it references line `480` of the file `rdd.jl`, which has only 178 lines.

This can be reproduced by checking out `https://github.com/peterjdolan/Spark.jl/tree/type_safety`

and running:

```
julia -e "using Spark"
```

There is some setup necessary to get that package running, which is documented in the `README.md` of https://github.com/dfdx/Spark.jl.

Thanks for any insight into this odd error message

Comment: I think that this issue could be caused by macro expansions. But looking at the file, there is only one `@assert`. :/

Comment: What Julia version?

Comment: @isaiah This is using Julia 0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message suggests that you have a function or type that has a hanging `T`, ie, `T` is not declared as a type parameter, but used in the body.

And sure enough, on line 63 of `rdd.jl`, you have the function defined

```
function source_eltype(nextrdd::Union{RDD{T}, Void})
```

That should instead be

```
function source_eltype{T}(nextrdd::Union{RDD{T}, Void})
```

Making that change fixes the error.

It is of course unfortunate that the line number is incorrect. There is an issue open about it at: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18764 . It manifests itself as incorrect line numbers when there are errors in functions that have docstrings on them (or more generally, are within macros)